# Attribute selection in h2o

Tags: h2o

I am very beginner in h2o and I want to know if there is any attribute selection capabilities in h2o framework so to be applied in h2oframes?

Answer (score 5):

No there are not currently feature selection functions in H2O -- my advice would be to use [Lasso regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) (in H2O this means use GLM with `alpha = 1.0`) to do the feature selection, or simply allow whatever machine learning algorithm (e.g. GBM) you are planning to use to use all the features (they'll tend to ignore the bad ones, but it could still degrade performance of the algorithm to have bad features in the training data).

If you'd like, you can make a feature request by filling out a ticket on the [H2O-3 JIRA](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV). This seems like a nice feature to have.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, based on the documentation, "The alpha parameter controls the distribution between the ℓ1ℓ1 (LASSO) and ℓ2ℓ2 (ridge regression) penalties. A value of 1.0 for alpha represents LASSO, and an alpha value of 0.0 produces ridge regression.", I think I should  make alpha as 1? I also don't want to use cross validation and need to apply attribute selection once on whole training set. Can I specify the number of most important attributes which the lasso should return?How to get the selected attributes from GLM then?

Comment: You're right.  I meant `alpha = 1.0` is Lasso and I will update my answer.  You will have to play around with the `lambda` parameter to increase or decrease the amount of regularization applied (which will lead to a larger or smaller number of coefficients being set to 0 in the model).  You can also use `max_active_predictors` to put a limit on the number of "active" (non-zero-weighted) features in the model.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Yes

My way is use automl to train your data.

after training, you can get a lot of model.

use ***h2o.get_model*** method or H2O server page to watch some model you like.

you can get **VARIABLE IMPORTANCES** frame.

then pick your features.