# H2O - Feature selection using LASSO in gridsearch

Tags: python, pandas, h2o, feature-selection, grid-search

I'm dealing with high dimensionality datasets and need to do some feature selection. I have used Random Forest in H2O and I would like to use LASSO regularization to see if it outperforms random forest.

Below is the code I created. When I specify alpha = 0 (RIDGE regularization), the code works fine and no error is raised. However, when I put alpha = 1 (LASSO) the error "ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero" is raised.

I followed the recommandation of this post for achieving LASSO : [Attribute selection in h2o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521080/attribute-selection-in-h2o)

Code :

```
from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
from h2o.grid.grid_search import H2OGridSearch

# feature columns et target column
x_lasso_h2o = list(feature_matrix.columns)
y_h2o = response_column

# select the values for lambda to grid over
hyper_params = {'lambda': list(arange(0.001,1,0.01))}

search_criteria_dim_reduction= {'strategy': 'RandomDiscrete',
                   'max_runtime_secs': 100,
                   'max_models': 5,
                   'stopping_metric': "auto",
                   'stopping_tolerance': 0.001,
                   'stopping_rounds': 5,
                   'seed': 1234}


# Train and validate a cartesian grid of GLMs
glm_grid_lasso = H2OGridSearch(model=H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family= "binomial",nfolds = 5,alpha = 1,balance_classes = True),hyper_params=hyper_params,search_criteria=search_criteria_dim_reduction)

glm_grid_lasso.train(x=x_lasso_h2o, y=y_h2o,training_frame= train_h2o)

# Get the grid results, sorted by validation AUC
glm_lasso_gridperf = glm_grid_lasso.get_grid(sort_by='auc', decreasing=True)

best_lasso = glm_lasso_gridperf.model_ids[0]
best_lasso = h2o.get_model(best_lasso)
var_imp_pd_lasso = pd.DataFrame(best_lasso.varimp(True))
```

The error raised is :

```
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-ca2e05533e82> in <module>
     32 best_lasso = glm_lasso_gridperf.model_ids[0]
     33 best_lasso = h2o.get_model(best_lasso)
---> 34 var_imp_pd_lasso = pd.DataFrame(best_lasso.varimp(True))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h2o\model\model_base.py in varimp(self, use_pandas)
    444                 vals = []
    445                 for item in tempvals:
--> 446                     tempT = (item[0], item[1], item[1]/maxVal, item[1]/sum)
    447                     vals.append(tempT)
    448                 header = ["variable", "relative_importance", "scaled_importance", "percentage"]

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

What I think : since LASSO reduces "non important" variables to 0 it explains why there is a division by 0 error. The output I expected was a list of all the variables with their respective importance.

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi BP34500 can you post the version of H2O-3 you are using? thanks for the code snippet!

Comment: Hello Lauren the H2O cluster version is 3.24.0.3.

Comment: Could it be possible that LASSO only works for regression problems (the response column is continuous) ?